# Function CollectionRefernce.doc() requires its first argument to be of type string

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on React-native and Firestore. To add the data in the firestore the following is the code :

```
    componentWillMount() {

      AsyncStorage.getItem("logid").then((value) => {
            this.setState({"logid":JSON.parse(value) });
        }).done();

        firebase.firestore().collection('mainmhealthdata').doc(this.state.logid).set({
          insta: 0
        })
```

I'm storing the logid in AsyncStorage and getting it into another screen in componentWillMount(). The above code for firestore is working fine on click events only but for react-native life cycle components its not working and the following error occurs:

[image: Firestore error]

In the firestore docs the doc("LA") is passed statically `db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})`

How to send the this static data into dynamic doc id?

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` call is asynchronous, see also the [React documentation for `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). By the time you're trying to use the state to write to the document, it hasn't propagated yet.

The simplest fix is to just use the same value to find the document:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('mainmhealthdata').doc(JSON.parse(value)).set({
  insta: 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cleared issue by using async/await method

```
async componentDidMount() {
const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem("LoginId")
console.log("result in calbmi is",res)
var parres= JSON.parse(res)
firebase.firestore().collection('mainmhealthdata').doc(parres).set({
  insta: 0
},{merge: true})
```

}